# Grabbing Details of Customers who appear more than once

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting a strange error with the below code. `No column was specified for column 2 of 'no1'.`
As far as I can tell it should work. I'm simply trying to get a collection of details about customers where the customers exist more than once on the receipts tbl.

```
SELECT
    CM.ClientID,
    CPN.Birthdate,
    CM.ClientPassword
FROM 
    dbo.ClientMaster AS CM
    JOIN dbo.ClientPerson AS CPN ON (CM.ClientID = CPN.ClientID)
    JOIN dbo.ClientProduct AS CP ON (CPN.ClientID = CP.ClientID)
WHERE 
    CM.ClientID IN (
                    SELECT 
                        no1.ClientID 
                    FROM 
                        (
                        SELECT 
                            CM.ClientID,
                            COUNT(*)
                        FROM 
                            dbo.ClientMaster AS CM
                            JOIN dbo.ClientPerson AS CPN ON (CM.ClientID = CPN.ClientID)
                            JOIN dbo.ClientProduct AS CP ON (CPN.ClientID = CP.ClientID)
                        WHERE
                            CP.PolicyNo IN (SELECT PolicyNo FROM Receipts)
                            AND CM.ClientID IS NOT NULL
                            AND Birthdate IS NOT NULL
                            AND ClientPassword IS NOT NULL
                        GROUP BY
                            CM.ClientID
                        HAVING 
                            COUNT(*)>1
                        ) AS no1
                    )
```

**SOLUTION**

Ah did not realise you don't need the `Count(*)` in the `Select`. Thanks guys!
This is what I ended up going with.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CM.ClientID,
    CPN.Birthdate,
    CM.ClientPassword
FROM 
    dbo.ClientMaster AS CM
    JOIN dbo.ClientPerson AS CPN ON (CM.ClientID = CPN.ClientID)
    JOIN dbo.ClientProduct AS CP ON (CPN.ClientID = CP.ClientID)
WHERE 
    CM.ClientID IN (
                        SELECT 
                            ClientID 
                        FROM 
                            Receipts
                        GROUP BY
                            ClientID
                        HAVING 
                            COUNT(*)>1
                        )
    AND CM.ClientID IS NOT NULL
    AND Birthdate IS NOT NULL
    AND ClientPassword IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your COUNT(*) column needs a name, like:

```
 COUNT(*) AS RecordCount
```

Comment: In fact, you don't even need this column in the result set, as you are only interested in ClientID, and you're using COUNT(*) in the HAVING clause - so there's no need to return it as a selected column

Comment: @MahmoudGamal He can put it in the HAVING part, and omit it from the SELECT part.

Comment: You can further improve your query by removing an unnecessary level of nesting. You've currently got: `WHERE X in (SELECT X FROM (SELECT X GROUPBY+HAVING))`. You only need: `WHERE X IN (SELECT X GROUPBY+HAVING)`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to nest the same query twice for that. You can do this instead:

```
SELECT
    CM.ClientID,
    CPN.Birthdate,
    CM.ClientPassword
FROM 
    dbo.ClientMaster AS CM
    JOIN dbo.ClientPerson AS CPN ON (CM.ClientID = CPN.ClientID)
    JOIN dbo.ClientProduct AS CP ON (CPN.ClientID = CP.ClientID)
GROUP BY CM.ClientID, CPN.Birthdate, CM.ClientPassword
HAVING COUNT(CM.ClientID) > 1
```

Comment: Interesting. Why did you group by all three columns?

Comment: @killianmcc, Typically when you `GROUP BY` the result set by a specific column, you need to determine what you need to do with the other columns in the result set that are not in the group by and you have two options: use an aggregate function for each column that is not in the group by or include it in the group by clause. If you remove the two columns from the `GROUP BY` clause and leave them in the SELECT statements you will got an error, Thats why I included them in the group by clause.